# package method no longer available in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am currently migrating my Laravel project from 4.2 to 5.3 and i've noticed that the `package()` method that usually existed in Laravel 4.2 is no longer available in `Illuminate\support\ServiceProvider.php` and therefore my code breaks since it used to use it.

Is there an alternative to this method?

I'm sorry in advance if this is a rookie question, i am not so familliar with the infrastructure of the Laravel files.